# Table View didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, xcode4.2, didselectrowatindexpath

I am having a problem with my project. I have a table view with subviews. I also have a search bar because of how big of an array I have. I have it that for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, if(indexpath.row==0){... But when I look up a word in the search bar what ever is in the first cell when you select it, it sends you to the subview of the first word of the array since it is setup to the first cell. How can I have it that the subview is linked to a certain word instead of just the integer of the rows so that if the cells word is 'Apple' then it will send me to the Apple Subview.

P.S. I am working on Xcode 4.2 with segues incase that makes a difference of my project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your approach. I think it would be more convenient to put `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) data in cells in your data delegate class. So when you find needed cell you can just load details view with a parameter of this `NSArray` object class instance. For example you use instances of `NSManagedObject` class in `NSArray`. (This is very common case because of usage of CoreData framework). So you should edit init method in your target view for receiving this class instance object and working with it. This is the main pattern of object-oriented programming. Or maybe there is some misunderstanding between us, what did you mean when you noticed "subview"? If you need to scroll table to calculated position depended on search bar input, why you don't like the most easy approach with indexPath?